# Operator overloading: calling friend function from member function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend-function

I have a Student class. I want to overload `+` operator so I can add a double variable to class. Here is `Student` class:

```
class Student {
private:
    std::string firstName;
    double grade;
public:
    Student(const std::string &firstName, double grade);

    double getGrade() const;

    friend Student operator+(double grade, const Student &student);

    Student operator+(double grade) const;
};
```

And implementation:

```
Student::Student(const std::string &firstName, double grade) {
    this->firstName = firstName;
    this->grade = grade;
}

double Student::getGrade() const {
    return grade;
}

Student operator+(double grade, const Student &student) {
    return Student(student.firstName, student.grade + grade);
}

Student Student::operator+(double grade) const {
    return operator+(grade, *this);
}
```

`double + Student` is done via friend function and `Student + double` goes through member function. When I compile I get this:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Student::operator+(double&, const Student&) const’
     return operator+(grade, *this);
                                  ^
note: candidate is:
note: Student Student::operator+(double) const
 Student Student::operator+(double grade) const {
         ^
note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Why I can't call a friend function from a member function?

**[UPDATE]**

However when I overload `<<` operator, I can call it from member function without pre-pending `::`.

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Student &student);
```

and the implementation:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Student &student) {
    os << student.grade;
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to call the member function, not the friend function (cfr. C++11 *7.3.1.2/3)*. You should rather write

```
Student Student::operator+(double grade) const {
    return ::operator+(grade, *this);
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e9dacb297e3fb85)</kbd>

Using the `::` makes sure overload resolution occurs from the global namespace you're currently in.

Another way (less readable in my opinion) is to add the friend function to the overload resolution set

```
Student Student::operator+(double grade) const {
    using ::operator+;
    return operator+(grade, *this);
}
```

or, more readable, as Jarod suggested,

```
Student Student::operator+(double grade) const {
    return grade + *this;
}
```

---

Edit: as for the "why": *[class.friend]/p7* and *[basic.lookup.argdep]/p3* explain that a member function with the same name "[hides](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18449855/1938163)" during overload resolution the name of the friend function.

Comment: or simply `grade + *this`

Comment: Your solution fixed the problem but raised another question. see the update.

Comment: @MajidAzimi Edited the post. Read along.